# Telegraf : Send message after Animation has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I need to send a gif file in a telegram bot, and then send a message, but only after the gif file has been sent.

```
bot.telegram.sendAnimation(ctx.chat.id,
    {source : 'path/to/gif/file'}
);
ctx.reply('This is the message text');
```

With the above code, it sends the message before the file (may be due to low internet speed.)

How can I send the file first?

Comment: you should put the result of sendAnimation inside a var, it will fill the var with the result of the sent message, including messageId, and then you can reply to that message id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the `sendAnimation` call with `async`/`await` or with `.then()` because it's a promise.